# Import js script to Angular from URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import, airconsole

i am building an app with angular but found a problem I don't know how to solve.
I need to import a js script and it has to be imported from the internet. (because these are their rules, so that they can do hotfixes)
The problem is, when I import the script into my index.html I can only use it in js files not in the typescript files. How can i use the libary in my ts files?
I can't install it via npm and i also can't download the file and add it to my project folder.
The libary is the airconsole API (https://developers.airconsole.com/#!/api)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's only add in your component `declare var AirConsole` to use it, a fool Component

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

declare var AirConsole //<--this is the "magic"

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  airConsole=new AirConsole() //<--now you can use airConsole in your component
}
```

**Update** Well, generally we can use a service to mannage the airConsole, this allow us that all components that inject the service can use the functions,variables,...

**Disclamer:** I don't know about "AirConsole", so I imagine control it like we can control others .js like Cordova)

As we need that Angular know when a function is executed in .js, our service can be like

```
import { Injectable,NgZone } from '@angular/core';

declare var AirConsole;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AirConsoleService implements OnInit {

  airConsole=new AirConsole()

  message:Subject=new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit(){
     this.airconsole.onMessage = (from, data)=>{
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.message.next({from:from,data:data})
      });

     })
  }

  message(device:any,message:any){
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.airConsole.message(device,message);
      });

  }
}
```

So, e.g. you can subscribe to `airConsoleService.message`

Comment: Tanks for your reply, I did my class like this: ´declare var AirConsole:any;

export var airconsole: any;

export function InitAirConsole(){
  airconsole = new AirConsole();
  console.log("Created AirConsole Controller:" );
  console.log(airconsole);
}´
It works but i get the following error in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'

Comment: @PatrickLangkau, Really I don't know about a AirConsole. I imagine You can use a service and I update the answer, but really I don't know if work or how can be use the service. I has no enought time to check or create a little example, sorry (and apologies if I only confused you)